# How to add a column from a file to another file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with two columns as

```
1 1
2 3
3 4
```

and a file with one column as

```
6
7
9
```

I would like to add the second file in the first one. The output should be:

```
1 1 6
2 3 7
3 4 9
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
$ pr -mts' ' file1 file2
1 1 6
2 3 7
3 4 9

$ paste -d' ' file1 file2
1 1 6
2 3 7
3 4 9
```

Comment: @fedorqui the default delimiter with `paste` is a tab.

Comment: i don t understand why when i print inside a file it puts the third column digit in a new row

Comment: paste -d' ' file1 file2 > file3

Comment: Very nice.  For reference, `paste -d' ' file1 file2` will paste `file2` to `file 1` (as an appended column) with a space as a delimiter; `paste -d'\t' file1 file2` will paste with a tab as a delimiter. E.g. `paste -d'\t' file1.tsv file2.tsv > test.tsv`.

Answer (score 12):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}{print a[FNR],$0}' file1 file2
```

**Note:** Will work with files of same length. If file lengths' are different, go with [sudo_O's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17095328/970195) solution.

---

Just for the heck of it, here is an `awk` command that I think should simulate `paste`. Purely for fun though, if I were you I would still go with [sudo_O's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17095328/970195) solution (or may be not!)

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[++y]=$0;next}{b[++x]=$0}
END{z=x>y?x:y;while(++i<=z){print a[i],b[i]}}' file1 file2
```

Comment: Pretty cool answer. Would you mind explaining how it works? I don't get why it's `a[NR]` first and then `a[FNR]`.

Comment: Or just print the result instead of building up the `b` array. Assuming the both file has the same size. But this solution is more general.

Answer (score 3):

A pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution can be:

```
echo -e "1 1\n2 3\n3 4" >onefile
echo -e "6\n7\n9" >twofile

exec 3<twofile
while read x; do read -u 3 y; echo $x $y; done <onefile
# exec 3<&- # Close the file, if not needed
```

or on a more general way:

```
exec {fd}<twofile
while read x; do read -u $fd y; echo $x $y; done <onefile
# exec $fd<&- # Close the file, if not needed
```

Output:

```
1 1 6
2 3 7
3 4 9
```