# Append one column from fileB onto end of FileA

Tags: bash

This is similar to

[How to add a column from a file to another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095306/how-to-add-a-column-from-a-file-to-another-file)

But In this case, I want to just use the 5th column from a 5 column file B. Both tab separated, of same length. Is there a way to do do this with awk ,paste or something?

```
file A
str str str 
str2 str2 str2

fileB
as at aw ay ao 
re rt ty yu ui

oFile
str str str ao
str2 str2 str2 ui
```

ExtraInfo, Im creating some similar files and I just want one column from most of them. sample full script, obv not right ;

```
 for pheno in $(seq 1 $nbGroups)
 do
    batch=$(sed -n $pheno'p' $Names)
    ## do some stuff to $batch

if [ $pheno=1 ] 
then
    awk '{ print $1, $1, $5}' $batch > $bDir"NewFile"
fi 
if [ $pheno>1 ] 
then
    awk '{ print $5}' $batch >> $bDir"File"
fi 

done
```

Comment: post an example along with expected output.

Comment: yep was just doing that thanks.

Comment: It's unclear how the 2nd snippet relates to your question - there's no discernible attempt to combine columns from multiple files.

Comment: I'm aware that it doesn't work. That's why I asked a question. No discernible effort is both rude and incorrect.

Comment: Are you actually using bash? If so, the numeric tests should be `((pheno==1))` and `((pheno>1))`. If you're limited to Posix shell features, you need `[ $pheno -eq 1 ]` and `[ $pheno -lt 1 ]`. The `test` built-in (also spelled `[`) reserves `=` and `>` for string comparison, and requires them to be separate words (i.e. surrounded by spaces; also, since `<`  and `>` are shell metacharacters, they need to be quoted. All this makes the `[[` and `((` constructions much less error-prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way, using bash process substitution

```
 paste file1 <(cut -f5 file2)
```

Without bash extensions:

```
 cut -f5 file2 | paste file1 -
```

Comment: Thanks rici. I went with the cut option because the ones with '<(' gave me a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below.

```
$ paste -d'\t' file1 <(awk '{print $NF}' file2)
str str str  ao
str2 str2 str2 ui
```

OR

```
$ paste -d'\t' file1 <(awk '{print $5}' file2)
str str str  ao
str2 str2 str2 ui
```

OR

```
paste file1 <(awk '{print $5}' file2)
```

Comment: In the OP is say's "Both tab separated" so shouldn't `paste -d' '` be `paste -d '\t'`  or even just `paste file1 ...` as the default delimiter for `paste` is a tab?