# How to directly append columns of one file to another file

Tags: bash, awk, cut, cat

Requirement: Only grep/cut/join/cat/regex/for/while.

I am a beginner at shell utilities.

I have fileA and fileB containing equal number of rows. I want to append columns of fileB into fileA.

I am trying this `(cat fileA && cat fileB) > fileC`. But it isn't working as required.

Expected:

fileA:

```
1
2
3
```

fileB:

```
1
2
3
```

then fileC should have:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a column from a file to another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095306/how-to-add-a-column-from-a-file-to-another-file)

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Please read requirements too

Comment: what is the OS used and may I know the reason behind restricting it to only those commands

Comment: OS is linux(ubuntu 18.04). I am bound to the given requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  read -r f1 <&3 || break
  read -r f2 <&4 || break
  echo "$f1 $f2"
done 3<fileA 4<fileB >fileC
```

Output to fileC:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

---

See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26604/74329

Comment: This is what I needed. Thanks

Comment: may I know the reason, why you added ````|| break````

Comment: Without `break` the infinite loop (`while true`) will never end. So the loop ends when fileA or fileB has been read to the end.

Comment: Why not `while read -r f1 <&3 && read -r f2 <&4; do printf '%s %s\n' "$f1" "$f2"; done 3<fileA 4<fileB >fileC` ?

Answer (score 0):

One way using Perl

```
$ perl -e ' BEGIN { @a=map{chomp;$_} qx(cat fileA); @b=map{chomp;$_} qx(cat fileB); printf("%s %s\n",$a[$_],$b[$_]) for (0..$#a) } '
1 1
2 2
3 3

$
```

Generally, it is done using paste command

```
$ paste -d" " fileA fileB
1 1
2 2
3 3

$
```

Your inputs

```
$ cat fileA
1
2
3

$ cat fileB
1
2
3

$
```

paste command just joins files vertically using the default tab delimiter. You can override the delimiter using the -d option

Comment: I suggested `paste` to OP in comments but OP told NOT allowed seems :)